# Variance of 3 point shots

Tags: variance

Suppose that each time Michael Jordan takes a 3-point shot, he has a 37% probability of success, independent of all other attempts. If Jordan takes seven 3-point shots in a game, what is the variance of the total number of points he scores from these shots?

0.37 chance of making the shot. 
So the variance of 7 shots being made is
7 * p (1-p) = 7 * (0.37) (1-0.37) = 1.63

How do you account for the 3 points that each shot is worth?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If $S$ is a random variable representing the number of three-pointers he makes, then $S$ has a binomial distribution with success probability $p=0.37$ across $n=7$ independent trials, with PMF

$$\mathrm{Pr}(S=s)=\begin{cases}\dbinom7s0.37^s(1-0.37)^{7-s}&\text{for }s\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,7\}\\[1ex]0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Each successful shot carries a value of $3$ points, so you can describe the number of points MJ gets by a new random variable, $P=3S$, whose variance would be $\mathrm{Var}[P]=3^2\mathrm{Var}[S]$.